# views exposed filters programmaticaly adding content titles as select list with content types

Tags: hooks, views

I have created a view which displays content types as select list with exposed filters as my requirements, I want to add a select list of content titles.
Example I have an content type article which consist article-1,article-2,...article-8 content titles.I want two select list boxes ,If I select articles in content type select list box .I should get content titles of articles as articl-1,article-2...article-8 in other .how can i get content title from exposed filters and display it programmaticaly.